# Marca un checkbox con javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Recibo información desde un arreglo y quiero que según lo que recibo, el check que tengo se active, he utilizado varias opciones y ninguna me funciona:

```
$("#inicio").prop("checked", true);
$('input[name="inicio"][value=' + info.inicioMes + ']').prop("checked", true);
document.getElementById("inicio").disabled = false;
$('input[name="inicio"]').prop("checked", true);
$("#inicio").attr("checked", "checked");
```

todo en javascript, por su ayuda gracias.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código HTML del input en cuestión? ¿Si tienes la librería de jQuery descargada en tu página?

Comment: `document.getElementById('inicio').checked = true;` debería funcionar siempre y cuando tu elemento html sea un `input type="checkbox"` con `id="inicio"`. Y no haya otro elemento en tu página que tenga ese id. Además, ese código javascript se debe ejecutar después de que la página haya cargado. Puedes probarlo desde la consola del navegador que uses.

Comment: Este es mi input <input type="checkbox" data-checkbox="icheckbox_square-blue" class="form-control input-sm" value="1" id="inicio" name="inicio"> Inicio de mes

Comment: En principio deberían funcionarte todas excepto la que cambia la propiedad  `disabled` salvo en los casos que te han comentado: que se ejecute antes de añadirse el elemento al DOM, que no esté cargado jQuery o que existan más de un elemento con el mismo `id`. Si modificas la pregunta e incluyes más código para mostrar el entorno en el que no te funciona quizás podamos decirte algo más.

Answer (score 0):

espero que esto te pueda ayudar:

```js
window.onload = () => {
  const data = ['Boat', 'Car', 'Truck'];
  const checkbox = document.querySelectorAll('[name="vehicle"]');
  checkbox.forEach(element => {
    let inData = data.findIndex(el => el === element.value);
    if (inData !== -1) {
      element.checked = true;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Boat"> I have a boat<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car"> I have a car<br>
```